# iwlist scan shows empty ESSID (ESSID: "") on Pi 3 with Raspbian

Tags: raspberry-pi, wifi, raspbian, raspberry-pi3, ssid

On Pi 3 with Raspbian (clean install) when I run:

```
sudo iwlist scan | grep ESSID
```

I can get both normal outputs and outputs with empty ESSID. E.g.:

```
ESSID: "SomeNetwork"
ESSID: ""
```

The list does not contain some networks which I can see through the web interface on my laptop, so I guess they are shown as having empty name.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

could be hidden ESSID Networks.

Here is the manual to connect to Hidden SSID

http://www.thehecklers.org/2015/02/27/how-to-connect-raspberry-pi-to-hidden-ssid/

Regards

Comment: Thanks! But isn't it the case that my laptop should have troubles seeing names of the hidden SSIDs? I have no troubles seeing them from my laptop though.